# `Event.ImageLoaded` event never triggered in FramerJS?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, framerjs

Here is my code, which can be pasted into Framer Studio directly:

```
layerA = new Layer()


# Listen to the loading event
layerA.on Events.ImageLoaded, -> 
    print "the image is loaded"

layerA.on Events.ImageLoadError, 
    -> print "the image could not be loaded"

layerA.image = "http://framerjs.com/static/images/home/app-icon.png"
```

However, I found the `the image is loaded` string is never printed.. Is it caused by cache? And does anyone have ideas about how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There was [an issue](https://github.com/koenbok/Framer/issues/236) related to the ImageLoaded event. It should be solved in the current version of Framer.

Comment: I can confirm that the example above is working now.